# Binding data from 2 sources into dataGrid

Tags: c#, list, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have made a UI that contains a `button` and `dataGrid`.
The `dataGrid`is binded with a `SampleDataSource` which is a column of images.

Once the button is clicked, the `dataGrid` should add 4 more lists (columns to the `dataGrid`), so the final output should be a `dataGrid` with 5 lists: 1 images 4 double.

The XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Property1Template">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Property1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Width="64"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Click="button_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="60" Margin="195,10,197,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Margin="0,10,47,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,85,10,10" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:Converter x:Key="conv" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                                <Binding Path="." />
                                <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="AmountNeed" Binding="{Binding AmountNeed}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalLose" Binding="{Binding TotalLose}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalGain" Binding="{Binding TotalGain}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalCost" Binding="{Binding TotalCost}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource Property1Template}" Header="Property1"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, the problem i get is when i click the `button` to add the data into the `dataGrid`with the following code:

```
        var L = new List<MyDataObject>();

        for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
        {

            var d = new MyDataObject();

            d.AmountNeed = Math.Ceiling((goalexp - currentexp) / (list_Exp[z]));
            d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
            d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
            d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;
            d.ImageSource = new Uri(@"path....", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            L.Add(d);

        }

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

it deletes the column with the images from `SampleDataSource`.

How can i make the 4 columns to be added into the `datagrid` instead of replacing the column of images?

Thank you.